# What's different between "put house down" and "put house up"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> 1. They **put their house down** as loan collateral.
> 2. He **put his house up** as collateral for his business loan.

What's different between 'down' and 'up' in these sentences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None.  They both have the same meaning.  The particles "up" and "down" can both signify the completion of an event or task, or the furtherance of an action.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly you can run for congress or stand for parliament. Which to use will be determined by the local convention or audience.